# What are the best practices for deploying a consul cluster?

Tags: consul

I'm trying to bring up a `consul` cluster for production purposes. I didn't find much information about best practices for deploying a consul cluster. Let's say I wanna have a cluster with 3 nodes. I'm wondering what's the difference between the following scenarios and which one is preferred.

- running `consul agent -server -data-dir /tmp/consul` on each node.
- running `consul agent -server -data-dir /tmp/consul --bootstrap` on
  only the first node.
- running `consul agent -server -data-dir
  /tmp/consul --bootstrap-expect 1` on each node or only the first node?
- running `consul agent -server -data-dir /tmp/consul
  --bootstrap-expect 3` on each node or only the first node?

Having done this initial step, then how should I cluster all 3 nodes together? Should I run `consul join <ip_node_1> <ip_node_2> <ip_node_3>` on each node or the fist node only?

If I wanna run the consul agent in docker containers, is it a good practice to mount `-data-dir` directory as a volume in host box?

Comment: You do not need to run bootstrap on production env. Bootstrap is used initially to join the nodes into cluster. I am running a cluster without bootstrap. You need once to add nodes into cluster then take it off. Also I feel to run consul in docker itself. I am also trying to achieve what you are trying. By the way if you had made any online post then do share.

Answer (score 4):

I believe your bullet #4 with `-bootstrap-expect` on each node is the preferred method.

From the [Consul bootstrapping documentation](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/bootstrapping.html):

> The recommended way to bootstrap is to use the -bootstrap-expect configuration option. This option informs Consul of the expected number of server nodes and automatically bootstraps when that many servers are available. To prevent inconsistencies and split-brain situations (that is, clusters where multiple servers consider themselves leader), all servers should either specify the same value for -bootstrap-expect or specify no value at all. Only servers that specify a value will attempt to bootstrap the cluster.

and your bullet #2 is discouraged based on [docs for -bootstrap-expect](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_bootstrap_expect) indicating that describe the `-bootstrap` flag as "legacy"

As for joining, I am using the [auto-join feature of the Atlas integration](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_atlas_join) so I don't need to manually join or specify the node IPs.

[This forum Q&A](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/consul-tool/9mkVmOGikzU) also helped to confirm this approach and provide some detail on what happens when `-bootstrap-expect` is used.